# Permalink to the most recent stable RStudio build?

Tags: rstudio, rstudio-server

Following the recipe provide [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/203842428-Getting-the-newest-RStudio-builds), I am trying to construct a permalink pointing at the current stable build of RStudio for RedHat/Fedora.

While the listed example listed for Ubuntu and the server version at the link above works (as does a link modified to point at the desktop version for Ubuntu), I just do not get this to work for the rpms.

Here's what I arrive at and what gives me `404`:

```
https://www.rstudio.com/ide/download/latest/stable/desktop/redhat64/rstudio-latest-x86_64.rpm
```

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Joh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever it was that made me go astray - here comes a link that works: [`http://www.rstudio.org/download/latest/stable/desktop/redhat64/rstudio-latest-x86_64.rpm`](http://www.rstudio.org/download/latest/stable/desktop/redhat64/rstudio-latest-x86_64.rpm).