# Permalink to the latest stable RStudio Server build for Redhat64?

Tags: rstudio, rpm, rstudio-server

Following the example [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/203842428-Getting-the-newest-RStudio-builds), I am trying to construct a permalink pointing at the current stable build of RStudio Server for RedHat64/CentOS.

While the example uses Ubuntu, I just do not get this to work for the rpms.

Here's what I arrive at and what gives me 404:

```
https://www.rstudio.org/download/latest/stable/server/redhat64/rstudio-server-rhel-latest-x86_64.rpm
```

I have also tried modifying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486926/permalink-to-the-most-recent-stable-rstudio-build) solution from StackOverflow for Rstudio *Desktop* to Server but no luck. Does anyone have the full working URL?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate to [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486926/permalink-to-the-most-recent-stable-rstudio-build/)

Try the following link:

> http://www.rstudio.org/download/latest/stable/desktop/redhat64/rstudio-latest-x86_64.rpm

Comment: As mentioned in OP, this other post and link are asking for Rstudio Desktop, not Rstudio Server. I have tried modifying this link to get Server edition but have not been able to hit it.